# Dynamic list for drop-down menu

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

In colunm "A" I have a list that will be filled up by the user; it starts at "A5" but I don't know where it will end.

In column "B" I'd like to make cells look like dropdown menus where items in the list will be the values from column "A".

And whenever the user adds a value to column "A" this should be automatically added to the list.

Comment: I tried with "Data Validation" functionality, but it requires a defined range of cells to include in the list, it is not dinamic as I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create named range (say `colA`) with formula:

```
=$A$5:INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(2,1/($A:$A<>"")))
```

[image]

and then use Data validation with named range `colA`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, there was a mistake in the formula (you put "," instead of ";") I corrected that but a the Data VAlidation it says "Origin currently evaluates to an error" and the cells look like drop-down menus but without list at all.

Comment: `you put "," instead of ";"` - actually it depend on your regional settings. Go to _Name Manager_ an check please formula in your named range (excel sometimes make wrong correction in named ranges formulae). If formula accidentally wrong, change it to correct one.

Comment: Yup, it was because my PC is in spanish. I also changed the names of functions INDEX = INDICE and MATCH = COINCIDIR

It works !!! thank you so much !!!!

But now I have a very small issue; if the users lets one cell blank, there will be a blank option in the list; how can I remove these blanks ?? is it possible?? maybe something in the range formula ??

Answer (score 0):

In Column A, set up your starting data list as a Table (select your list and then Insert/Table).
Give your new table a nice name (select the Table then go to Table Tools/Design/Table Name).
Tables in Excel automatically expand when a new value is added to an existing Table.

Next, select this same starting data list and create a Named Range.  Go to Formulas/Define Name.
Give your list a Name (for example, "List"), and in Refers To enter your Table name. (e.g. type "=Table1" if that's the name of your Table)

I am assuming that for your Column B, you want Data Validation - it puts the dropdowns in each cell as you suggest.
Select the range of cells that you are going to validate, then go to Data/Data Validation.
Under Settings, choose Allow = List.
Under Source type the name of your Named Range that you set up in Column A. (e.g. type "=List").
Add an Input and Output message to your Validation (optional but helpful).
Click OK to close.

Credit to Chandoo.org where I learned this.